# Solr: How to get Facets with matching keywords

Tags: solr, solrnet

I am not sure if this is possible or what's the best way to do it? How can I get facet count in Solr where it counts as in following example.

Let's say I have got following values equal to the number of times they repeat in a field..

Tv = 100

Sony Tv = 10

LG Tv=10

Nokia Mobile= 5

iPhone Mobile = 4

If a user query is 'tv & mobile'. Based on above values in a field, How can I get the facets like...

Tv (120)

Mobile (9)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comment you gave to Jayendra's answer, you want to leverage Solr [MultiValued](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaXml#Data_Types) fields to store those values and then facet on that multiValued field. This would give you the behavior you want for faceting.

Additionally, if you want to limit the facet results to a specific set of values, you will to supply a [facet.query](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SimpleFacetParameters#facet.query_%3a_Arbitrary_Query_Faceting) along with your request to Solr.

Comment: thanks you so much for this. I think this would work.. I am still developing the system and will let you know if it works. thanks again!

Comment: I am really new to Solr and I think i am struggling with facet.query, Can you please type in an example of facet.query? My filed name is 'Title' and search keywords is 'tv'. I am trying facet.query={! qf='Title' v='tv'}

Comment: Your facet.query would be `facet.query=Title:tv` does not require anything fancier than that.

Comment: Thanks Paige. That works! Just need a little help if u could do it.  There is a facet.prefix option which would prefix a given keyword. Is it possible to do the same thing where prefix keyword is not just the prefix but it could be anywhere in the field 'Title'?

Answer (score 0):

You can index the data in hierarchy form and use [Solr Pivots](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/HierarchicalFaceting#Pivot_Facets) to implement this facet.

e.g. tv/sony, tv/LG, mobile/Nokia & mobile/iPhone

This would help you to facet over parent and further drill down on the same.

Comment: I think my example is not good enough. Actually, field values cannot be indexed as categories and sub categories. I need a way to get a facet and count based on user search. For example if I have three records like... java developer, java programmer,java software developer; and user searches for keyword 'java'. I need a way to create facets: java(3), developer(2).